# React-Text-Mask with Material UI not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Seen this done a million different ways and an cannot get it to work any of those ways.  I would like to use react-text-mask with material UI but all I get are errors and frustration so here is my latest attempt:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import {MaskedInput} from "react-text-mask";

const PhoneInput = ({ inputRef, ...props }) => (
    <MaskedInput
        {...props}
        ref={ref => { inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null) }}
        mask={['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
        placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
    />    
);

export const FormTelephone = (props) =>{
    return(<>
        <TextField label="Telephone" InputProps={{inputComponent:PhoneInput}} />
    </>)
}
```

And the app errors out with:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `inputComponent` supplied to `ForwardRef(InputBase)`. Expected an element type that can hold a ref. Did you accidentally provide a plain function component instead? For more information see https://mui.com/r/caveat-with-refs-guide
```

I don't understand how all of these work online but I am stuck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The error message is telling you that it expects an element type that can hold a ref, but it looks like PhoneInput is not providing that. To make it work, you need to wrap your PhoneInput component with React.forwardRef.

Comment: Thanks Mile.  Tried your suggestion but the error pit grows bigger.  It doesn't work.  Haven't seen an example with forwardRef being implemented.